# mysql show products and total quantity where status is completed

Tags: mysql

I want to show the list of products, stock, and the total ordered quantity of them from `orders` that is `Completed`.

I have this query but it's throwing error and it's not complete.

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, op.item_id, o.status SUM( op.quantity ) as quantity
FROM  `orders` o JOIN 
      order_items op
      ON op.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY op.item_id, o.id
ORDER BY o.id, op.item_id;
```

Expected Output:

```
+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
|  Product    |  Total Ordered Quantity  |    Stock    |
+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
|  Product A  |            5             |      8      |
|  Product B  |            2             |      9      |
|  Product C  |            1             |      7      |
+-------------+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Order Table

```
+-----------+-----+-----------+
|  ID |   User ID |  Total    |
+-----------------+-----------+
|  1  |     1     |    500    |
|  2  |     1     |    200    |
|  3  |     2     |    100    |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

Order Items Table

```
+-----------+-----+-------------+------------+
|  ID |  Order ID |  Product ID |  Quantity  |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+
|  1  |     1     |      1      |     4      |
|  2  |     1     |      2      |     2      |
|  3  |     2     |      3      |     1      |
|  4  |     3     |      1      |     1      |
+-----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Products Table

```
+-----+-------------+-----------------+
|  ID |     Name    |   Total Stock   |
+-------------------+-----------------+
|  1  |  Product A  |        8        |
|  2  |  Product B  |        9        | 
|  3  |  Product C  |        7        |
+-----+-------------+-----------------+
```

EDIT:

I have update my query to this and it is working, Now I only need to show the product name and stock just like the expected output above.

```
SELECT o.id, o.name, op.item_id, o.status, SUM( op.quantity ) as quantity
FROM  `orders` o JOIN 
      order_items op
      ON op.order_id = o.id
WHERE o.status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY op.item_id, o.id
ORDER BY o.id, op.item_id;
```

Comment: What is the error? There is also no need to group on order, `GROUP BY op.item_id` should be enough. You'll also need to JOIN the products on op.item_id = products.id to select the products.total_stock value.

Comment: The pasted query is also missing a 'comma' between o.status and SUM.. in your select statement

Comment: let me try to add.

Comment: I add the comma and it's working now, but I want to show the product name and the current stock as expected output added on the question.

Comment: Am i loosing it? You dont have a `status` column in your `orders` table` ???? Or a `name` column ??? + + +

Comment: let's just assume @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how your columns are named, but this should be the gist of it then.

Joined the products on the order items, so you can select the product information.

```
SELECT p.product_name, SUM(op.quantity) AS quantity, p.total_stock 
FROM  `orders` o 
JOIN 
      order_items op
      ON op.order_id = o.id
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = op.item_id      
WHERE o.status = 'Completed'
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.product_name;
```

Comment: This assumes a functional dependency on p.id which, to be fair, is not an unreasonable assumption

Comment: tip. As you are after products, start that as the `FROM` clause. You'd `LEFT JOIN` to orders,order_items is you want 0 values for products that weren't ordered, otherwise `JOIN` is sufficient.